# How to generate an XML out of the results of JUNIT and configuring ant for using it?

Tags: java, xml, junit

I am new to JUNIT and stuck somewhere here. I am trying to generate a report programatically.How do i create an XML out of the results that i get from JUNIT testing. I am open to using ant but honestly i am not sure how do i confgure ANT with my project first. Please find the below code of my JSP where i get my results. These result i want to convert in the form of XML. How can the results be parsed to XML. Any help much apprecitated..

**TestJUnit.JSP**

```
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.PrintStream"%>
<%@page import="org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" errorPage="error.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@ page import="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"%>
<%@ page import="org.junit.runner.Result"%>
<%@ page import="com.test.service.ejb.session.ServiceRemote"%>
<%@ page import="com.test.service.ejb.session.MasterDataServiceRemote"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger"%>
<%@ page import="test.com.test.service.ejb.session.AllEJBJunitTests"%>
<%@ page import="test.com.test.service.ejb.session.EGDSVJunitListener"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Runner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    System.out.print("Test");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TestJunit.jsp");
        logger.debug("Calling Junit");
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Class[] tests = { AllEJBJunitTests.class};
        Result result= junit.runClasses(tests);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);             
        junit.addListener(new TextListener(ps));
        junit.run(AllEJBJunitTests.class);
        response.setHeader("value", new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
        logger.debug("Stop Junit"+ result.getRunCount());



    %>
</body>
</html>
```

**TextListener.java**

```
package test.com.egdsv.service.ejb.session;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.internal.JUnitSystem;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

public class TextListener extends RunListener {

    private final PrintStream writer;


    public TextListener(JUnitSystem system) {
        this(system.out());
    }

    public TextListener(PrintStream writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) {
        printHeader(result.getRunTime());
        printFailures(result);
        printFooter(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(Description description) {
        writer.append('.');
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
        writer.append('E');
    }

    @Override
    public void testIgnored(Description description) {
        writer.append('I');
    }

    /*
      * Internal methods
      */

    private PrintStream getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }

    protected void printHeader(long runTime) {
        getWriter().println();
        getWriter().println("Time: " + elapsedTimeAsString(runTime));
    }

    protected void printFailures(Result result) {
        List<Failure> failures = result.getFailures();
        if (failures.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (failures.size() == 1) {
            getWriter().println("There was " + failures.size() + " failure:");
        } else {
            getWriter().println("There were " + failures.size() + " failures:");
        }
        int i = 1;
        for (Failure each : failures) {
            printFailure(each, "" + i++);
        }
    }

    protected void printFailure(Failure each, String prefix) {
        getWriter().println(prefix + ") " + each.getTestHeader());
        getWriter().print(each.getTrace());
    }

    protected void printFooter(Result result) {
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            getWriter().println();
            getWriter().print("OK");
            getWriter().println(" (" + result.getRunCount() + " test" + (result.getRunCount() == 1 ? "" : "s") + ")");

        } else {
            getWriter().println();
            getWriter().println("FAILURES!!!");
            getWriter().println("Tests run: " + result.getRunCount() + ",  Failures: " + result.getFailureCount());
        }
        getWriter().println();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the formatted string of the elapsed time. Duplicated from
     * BaseTestRunner. Fix it.
     */
    protected String elapsedTimeAsString(long runTime) {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance().format((double) runTime / 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont fully know your requirements but if you want to serialize a object as XML without any big effort i recomend you have a look at XStream -> http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html.

(Remember you have the possibility to create a new "Wrapper" Class that just holds the interesting parts of your Report-objects and "well speaking" fieldnames and then serialize this one.)

Unfortunately XStream has its limit when it comes to very complex structures where i guess JAXB with its definitions (ObjectFactorys and stuff) on how to Marshall/ Unmarshall Objects kicks in.

Another possibility is to have a Simple "XML Converter" that prints out like this and sometimes is the fastest way to get a desired XML Output (especially if you just need a quick and hacky solution).

```
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
b.append("<TestResult>");
 for(Result tmpRes : results){
   b.append("<TestResult><TestCaseName>");
   b.append(tmpRes.getTestCaseName());
   b.append("</TestCaseName>");
   ...
  }
b.appebnd("</TestResult");
```

Above code just shall show the quick way, i assume the Result class wont have a method getTestCaseName() but i guess you see what i mean ;)

(I maybe totaly missunderstood you since i dont see the link to Ant. Excuse me in this case)